# jquery: submit form serialize

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi first of all I'm from uruguay so sorry for my english,

I have this form

```
<form id="filtros" name="filtros" method="post">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-0 col-md-6 tipe-prod">
                        <select name="select-prod" id="select-prod">
                            <option value="" onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Seleccionar producto</option>
                            <option value="">Producto 2</option>
                            <option value="">Producto 3</option>
                            <option value="">Producto 4</option>
                            <option value="">Producto 5</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="order-prod" id="select-ord" onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()">
                            <option value="">Ordenar por</option>
                            <option value="">Orden 1</option>
                            <option value="">Orden 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-0 col-md-6 tipe-prod">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="icon-tipe-cont sin-sal">
                                    <div class="icon-cont-top">
                                        <div class="icono grey"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="sin-sal">Sin sal añadida</label>
                                    <input id="sin-sal" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()" />
                                    <label for="sin-sal" class="css-label"></label>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--
                            --><li>
                                <div class="icon-tipe-cont vegetal">
                                    <div class="icon-cont-top">
                                        <div class="icono green"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="vegetal">Vegetarianos</label>
                                    <input id="vegetal" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()" />
                                    <label for="vegetal" class="css-label"></label>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--
                            --><li>
                                <div class="icon-tipe-cont bajas-cal">
                                    <div class="icon-cont-top">
                                        <div class="icono brown"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="bajas-cal">Bajas calorias</label>
                                    <input id="bajas-cal" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()" />
                                    <label for="bajas-cal" class="css-label"></label>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--
                            --><li>
                                <div class="icon-tipe-cont sin-azucar">
                                    <div class="icon-cont-top">
                                        <div class="icono orange"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="sin-azucar">Sin azúcar</label>
                                    <input id="sin-azucar" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()" />
                                    <label for="sin-azucar" class="css-label"></label>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--
                            --><li>
                                <div class="icon-tipe-cont all">
                                    <div class="icon-cont-top"></div>
                                    <label for="todos">Todos</label>
                                    <input id="todos" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
                                    <label for="todos" class="css-label"></label>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

The idea is that this form is submitted by the change of any of the selects or the checkboxes, then is processed by this jquery script:

```
<script>   
    $(function(){
     $("#filtros").submit(function(){
     var url = "process.php"; //Funciones para procesar el formulario
     var cargando = document.getElementById("cargando");
     var content  = document.getElementById("contenido_productos");
         content.style.display='none';
         cargando.style.display='block';
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#filtros").serialize(), //ID del formulario
               success: function(data)
               {
                    cargando.style.display='none';
                    $("#contenido_productos").load(url);
               }
             });

        return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
     });
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is that never reach success. The code is just and example

Comment: Try `.submit(function(e){ /*...*/ e.preventDefault();return false;});` // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to submit the form when changing any selects or checkboxes ?

Add an event handler for the checkboxes and selects that triggers the submit

```
$(function () {
    $("#filtros").submit(function () {
        var url      = "process.php";
        var cargando = $("#cargando").hide();
        var content  = $("#contenido_productos").show();

        $.ajax({
            type   : "POST",
            url    : url,
            data   : $("#filtros").serialize(), //ID del formulario
            success: function (data) {
                cargando.hide();
                content.html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }).find('select, input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        $("#filtros").trigger('submit');
    })
});
```

Comment: To submit the form I use this in every select and checkbox: onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()"

Comment: Didn't notice the horrid inline jQuery, remove it!

Comment: do not do that remove all that and replace for $('div#contenedor select, input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        $("#filtros").trigger('submit');
})

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, I'm a jquery ignorant right now, I'm learning. but this" success: function (data) {
                cargando.hide();
                content.load(url);
            }" 
doesnt work at all :(

Comment: Then open the browser console (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: the load is the problem there, i dont know why, but if i remove it, it works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my English I am from Uruguay too.

First of all I must say that you must attach an event listener to the changes on any select or checkboxes, for this I recommend you to wrap all that inside a div, let say

Then attach listener to that:

```
$('div#contenedor select, input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        $("#filtros").trigger('submit');
})
```

Also use #cargando to fetch by id and not use document.getElementById()

```
 $("#filtros").submit(function () {
        var url      = "process.php";
        var cargando = $("#cargando").hide();
        var content  = $("#contenido_productos").show();

        $.ajax({
            type   : "POST",
            url    : url,
            data   : $("#filtros").serialize(), //ID del formulario
            success: function (data) {
                cargando.hide();
                content.load(url);
            }
        });

        return false;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I do add that, but is still falling before the success event

Comment: did you tried to define error: function() to see what is going on? Also you can try make a console.log(data) in the first line of your success function to dump what it got